# Loading column selectively from TSV in Redshift

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, ddl, create-table

I am loading a *TSV file* from *S3 file* in a RedShift table. TSV file has 10 columns.

I want to select only column 2 and 5 from that CSV.

Previously I was using the *COPY* command to create table. Can I selectively specify I want to select column 2 and 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this (currently) with a COPY command.  The target table and the CSV/TSV file being loaded need to have the same columns.  You can COPY to a temp table with all the columns then insert the needed data into your table.

If this doesn't work for you then define an external table that points to the CSV file and insert from the external table to your target.